# count how many people who buy the same item at second time and how many people who did not buy the second item at second time (compare to firsttime)

Tags: sql-server

Here is the question:count how many people who buy the same item at second time and how many people who did not buy the second item at second time (compare to `buying_order = 1`)

One customer can purchase many items, if the buying_order = 1 indicates that customer buy that item at the first time. It is not the number of purchases.

We have a table:

| id | item | date | buying_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 19990101 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 19990102 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 19990102 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 19990101 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 19990103 | 1 |

To be more clear, if `id 1` buy `item 1` on `19990101`, that is the first purchased item so the `buying_order` is 1. Our concern is know how many people buy a specific item at their first time, and how many people re-purchase that specific item at the second time.

Here are the logic I have tried, but not work

```
SELECT a.id FROM (SELECT id FROM table WHERE buying_order = 1) AS a 
LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.buying_order=2 and a.item = b.item
```

Expected result:

| item | first_purchase_customer | second_purchase | second_buy_other_item_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

For `item 1`, there are two first purchase at `order 1`, and there is only one customer buy `item 1` at `order 2`.

**NOTE: The order can be higher than 2, such that `order = 3,4,..., but we only care the people who buy or not buy the same item at their second purchase.`**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I change the ```order``` to ```buying_order```

Comment: Why did `first_purchase_customer = 2` and `second_purchase=1` from your expect result

Comment: For ```item1```, there are ```id 1 and 2``` make their first purchase (buying_order = 1), so there are totally 2 customer buying ```item 1 ``` at their first time .

Comment: bring more clarity to your question.

Comment: You have tagged conflicting RDBMS - please correct your tags

Comment: Still not that clear in what is needed, dont undersand what buying_order is for.

Comment: Are you expecting help for MySql or Sql Server???

Comment: SQL Server (the one does not have the DATE_FORMAT function)

Comment: So why tag both SQL Server and MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a hugely clear question. I would also raises questions why you even have the buying_order column, as it really doesn't seem to add value, you already have a row per user and item and also a date!

You could simply do this to count the orders, again ignoring the buying_order column altogether

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (
    UserId INT NOT NULL, 
    ItemId INT NOT NULL, 
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL, 
    BuyingOrder INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #MyTable(UserId, ItemId, [Date], BuyingOrder)
VALUES
(1, 1, '19990101', 1),
(1, 1, '19990102', 2),
(2, 1, '19990102', 1),
(2, 2, '19990101', 2),
(2, 3, '19990103', 1);

GO

SELECT UserId, ItemId, COUNT(*) NumberOfTimesBought
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY UserId, ItemId
```

[image]

I was also thinking you could use the ROW_NUMBER solution as follows, which will just give you the items that have been bought more than once:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT 
    UserId, 
    ItemId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId, ItemId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM
    #MyTable
)

SELECT UserId, ItemId
FROM T
WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

Comment: One customer can purchase many items, if the ```buying_order = 1``` indicates that customer buy that item at the first time. It is not the ```number of purchases```.

Comment: If you are saying that buying_order = 1 to signify that it was bough for the first time, again that is redundant as you have a date column, so like the ROW_NUMBER example I put; this uses the date so you know any RowNumber that equals 1 is the first order. In the real world I imagine you would have the time as well, incase they order that item more than once on that day.